# Micronaut microservice can only handle 16 concurrent http connections

Tags: netty, micronaut

We have a micronaut microservice with a bottleneck on 16 concurrent http connections. We tried increasing number of threads for netty worker and executors, no luck:

```
micronaut:
  executors:
    io:
      type: fixed
      nThreads: 150
  server:
    host: localhost
    netty:
      worker:
        threads: 100
      parent:
        threads: 100
      childOptions:
        autoRead: true
```

We use Micronaut version 2.0.1 and netty http server.

Comment: "We tried increasing number of threads for netty worker and executors, no luck." - What technique(s) did you employ to do that?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown We set the following properties to application.yml: `executors:
    io:
      type: fixed
      nThreads: 150
  server:
    host: localhost
    netty:
      worker:
        threads: 100
      parent:
        threads: 100`

Comment: @JeffScottBrown We also set  `@ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.IO)` on the controller method.

Comment: It looks like your config settings start with `executors.`.  In your real app do they start with `micronaut.executors.`?

Comment: For example, `micronaut.executors.io.type.fixed` and `micronaut.executors.io.type.nThreads`.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @JeffScottBrown my bad, we have `micronaut` before the mentioned properties, I just gave this part, where these properties are set. I did not want to show you my whole application.yml.

Comment: "I did not want to show you my whole application.yml" - That isn't a problem.  What you have in the question now is better than the screenshot that was there.  Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @NinoZalascek Did you solve this problem?